# If you seek(0) after reading a csv file, the line_num attribute does not resets. Why does this happens?

Tags: python, csv, pointers

I was trying a few combinations to read a csv file and noticed that after reading it when I `seek(0)` to return back to the starting position it was not resetting `line_num` attribute. Why does this happen?

```
>>> fileR
<_csv.reader object at 0x0761ADF0>
>>> for a in fileR:
...     print('line#' + str(fileR.line_num) + ' ' + str(a))
...
line#4 ['1', '1', '1001']
line#5 ['2', '2', '2002']
line#6 ['Day', 'Month', 'Year']
>>> file.seek(0)
0
>>> for a in fileR:
...     print('line#' + str(fileR.line_num) + ' ' + str(a))
...
line#7 ['1', '1', '1001']
line#8 ['2', '2', '2002']
line#9 ['Day', 'Month', 'Year']
```

Comment: If you use `csv.reader` a file to work with, it expects to be in charge of reading the file. If you do a `seek()` at file level behind its back, it has no way to detect that you have done that. You have to choose between (1) leaving `csv.reader` in charge of reading the physical file, or (2) taking low-level control of the file and picking the data apart yourself.

Comment: Oke, that's interesting. I thought when csv.reader was not able to read the file again i was helping it by seek(0). When i seek(0) and read the contents again it is able to read it , its just that the line_num is not resetting. What confuses me is that on one hand seek(0) works find(when we have to read the elements again) on other it does not(when i have to figure out the line num).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[line_num](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvreader.line_num) is:

> The number of lines read from the source iterator.

This is not the same as the location of the file pointer.  `line_num` is set in `C` code and cannot be changed directly from Python code.  There is no information in the [commit message](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/7f2053eff3ec1ee9084a3a550ae363a804368322) to explain why `line_num` isn't reset if the file pointer is reset.

If you want to track line numbers per iteration use can use the [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) built-in function instead, or implement your own counter.

```py
>>> for i, a in enumerate(fileR):
...     print('line#', i, str(a))
```

Comment: This approach works and i am getting the correct line#. Interestingly, line_num also increased after using this approach :)